# Transfer Session ID from ASP.NET to ASP

Tags: asp.net, session, asp-classic

Recently I have this problem for module by module migration from ASP to ASP.NET. I've already set up a session table in my database for ASP session using after redirected from ASP.NET module. But when I want to use that session ID I already stored, I found a problem. I found that the session ID between this two is different.

For ASP it looks like `342417338` while for ASP.NET it looks like `qvc0i13jvmzce3ny5jzxpaci`

Is there any way to convert that session ID from ASP.NET to ASP and vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you are passing from asp.net to asp thenEncode your session value and pass with the help of query string and catch this session value at page level and decode using some encode and decode methods.

if your passing from asp to asp.net in global.asax page in session_start method you can catch by using session cokies. like some example I am giving u can follow it

```
       if (null == Request.Cookies["SessionCookie"])
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            Response.Redirect("../../aspx/login/login.aspx");
        }
        else //if the user is in session get the userid from guid.
        {
            Session["UserId"] =Request.Cookies["SessionCookie"].Value//this value ucan get as GUID from the url and u can decode                
        }
```

Comment: Worth to try I think. What kind of encode method I should use?

Comment: Forget to mark this as an answer, sorry. Anyway thanks! It works miraculously.

Answer (score 0):

1. ASP and ASP.NET sessions are not shareable.
2. We would need something intermediate so that there is minimal
   rewriting of code.
3. We should be able to uniquely identify each client's session.

Check this [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8654/Transfering-session-state-between-ASP-and-ASP-NET) Post.